# Kate doesn't show text

Tags: kate

A couple of hours ago, everything worked fine. I don't know what happened, but now Kate does not show any file content:

[image]

I could not find any options to fix this. I uninstalled and reinstalled it. I renamed all files in the subfolders of ~/.kde/share that have "kate" in their names. No change. KWrite works fine.

Comment: Did you change the [Qt or KDE] theme?   The only time I've had this occur was the text was the same color as the background of a program (thus invisible) because I changed a theme...  (*I don't currently use Qt/KDE so theme may be the incorrect word, if so sorry*).   Also this is more easily happens if you're not using KDE but another DEsktop which mis-interprets a theme you've selected in my experience.

Comment: I changed the appearance of the text within Kate to something similar to Vim style. This worked fine until this morning, and it still works fine in KWrite. Globally, I did not deliberately make any changes to the options of KDE or whatever, it's pretty much a plain Ubuntu 17.10. Kate is (pre-installed) version 17.04.

Comment: Your Ubuntu is GNOME (GTK+ based), Kate is a Qt (used by KDE) based editor thus you can get glitches like this on rare occasion by changing a theme in one that creates unusual glitches in the other toolkit.  Kate (the version you mentioned) does not come with Ubuntu 17.10 (only Kubuntu 17.10) as it doesn't use the default GTK+ libraries, and by installing it you've dragged into your system the parts of KDE/Qt needed to run Kate.  I realize you didn't do it (change) on purpose, (it's happened to me & I didn't mean it) but I usually can undo the theme changes I made fixing it...

Comment: Ok, that's an idea. Do you have any suggestions how to undo the theme changes? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've assumed you are using Ubuntu 17.10 (which uses GTK+.  What I've said is based on that (though it applies to xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-mate that also use GTK+ too).  If however you are using Kubuntu 17.10 (or LXQt) what I've suggested does not apply.  I don't directly have a fix; I suggested it hoping it'd trigger a memory on what you changed, so you could attempt to undo it.  If you can't remember, I'd suggest you look for files with a modified time/date around when you think it started (eg last 5 days; `find -mtime 5`) & hoping that jogs your memory, or finds the file to undo your change.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. However, my OS also has more and more other malfunctions, so I choose to just re-install the whole thing on a clean partition. Thanks again.